# JS "Greater than" operator;

Tags: javascript

This expression:

```
'33.33' > '100.00'
```

return `true`. Why?

If it work like:

```
+'33.33' > +'100.00'
```

it must return `false` because 33.33 < 100;

If like:

```
'33.33'.length > '100.00'.length
```

then `false`, because 5 < 6;

I'm really interested know, how it work in the first case;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I feel ashamed. While I wrote & formated this post, I find the answer.

For string compare JS use [Lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order); So, in this case we have just:

```
'3' > '1'
```

and it's really `true`.

Maybe it would be interesting for someone.